# Vue - Optimal way of receiving notifications from back-end

Tags: django, vue.js, websocket, notifications, polling

I'm adding backend-sent notifications to my Vue 3 app.

My Django backend generates notifications and saves them to the user inbox; where they can be accessed and read at any time.

I'm trying to decide which way is best for the front-end to receive such notifications. Basically, I'm torn between two options:

- use polling; something like a `setInterval` of 20 seconds that simply makes a REST call to get the most recent notifications for the user
- open a websocket; the server pushes a message each time there's a new notification

I'm leaning a little more towards the websocket option; however, I am concerned with:

1. complexity: having to manage re-connections and all the things that can go wrong with a WS
2. performance: I am predicting peaks of 200-300 users at a time; is having that many open WS connection a possible concern?

Weighing these factors, which one would be the better choice for my needs? And how would you mitigate the drawbacks of the chosen approach?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best solution for a notification system would be to use WebScokets such as socket.io. If you use HTTP requests, the server will receive about 300 requests at a time every few tens of seconds which can be aggravating for the server. In this most of the requests may not be necessary (the user has not received any notifications). Using sockets the server will only send a notification to the client when it receives a notification. Another advantage of sockets is that the notification will come immediately, rather than every specified interval. So to summarise:

WebSockets advantages for a notification system:

- Less load on the server and more efficient operation (much better performance)
- More comprehensive notification system
- Possibility of later extension with other 'server push' data

Disadvantages:

- Longer and more difficult to implement than REST communication

Comment: How does having 300 WS connections at a time compare to having 300 HTTP requests from a server load standpoint? My only issue with going the websocket path is that nowhere else does my app use websockets, so I'd create those connections ex novo and at this time I have no data to predict how that will affect load on the server

Comment: I think with WS we mostly exclude the situation with 300 request per time, because WS will only push data when user receive new notification. With HTTP you always force to send 300 requests every some period of time. With the use of WS you relieve the server in advance. Because if you don't need to send 300 requests every so often, why send them? Here are some benchmarks of socket.io and http requests take a look: https://blog.feathersjs.com/http-vs-websockets-a-performance-comparison-da2533f13a77

Answer (score 0):

WebSocket is the best solution in your case. I used [vue-native-websocket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-native-websocket) plugin.